# About doublyLinkedList

Tags: java

I need to build a doubly LinkedList which takes a String and build node for each character in it.

```
public class doublyLinkedlist{
    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    public doublyLinkedList(String a){
        first=new Node(a.charAt(0),null);
        last=new Node(a.charAt(1),first);
    }
}
```

So if I have a `String "ab"`,the The first contains "a", last contains"b".

But this is not what I want. My constructor should be able to build Nodes for each `char` in `String`. Can someone explain to me how doubly LinkedList works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you defining your Node class? try something like

```
  class Node
{
  String val;

  Node next, prev;

  public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public Node getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public void setPrev(Node prev) {
    this.prev = prev;
}

public Node(String v)
  {
      val=v;
  }
```

you would need to add functions to set the next and prev Nodes. Now in the constructor of your doublyLinkedlist class, you just basically split the input string and create one Node per character. Also, set the next and prev accordingly. does that help? i can provide more detailed code if needed, but i would urge you to try.

ok, so your doublyLinkedlist  constructor will look like

```
public doublyLinkedlist(String a) {

         String [] arr = a.split("");

         first = new Node(arr[0]);

         last = new Node(arr[arr.length-1]);

         first.setPrev(last);

         last.setNext(first);
         Node temp = first;
         for (int i=1 ; i<arr.length-1 ; i++)
         {
             Node newNode = new Node(arr[i]);
             temp.setNext(newNode);
             newNode.setPrev(temp);

             temp = temp.next;
         }

         //finally

         temp.prev.next = temp;
    }
```

Comment: also, note that you might need to create a temp Node to make sure that your head Node does not move after creation. does that make sense?

Comment: please see the latest edit now. the Node class can be a separate class or a be a part of the doublyLinkedlist class

Comment: glad to help. all the best :). please upvote the answer if you find it useful. thanks